# django virtualenv mimeparse import error

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, importerror

I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong, here's what's going on:

- I'm running google appengine with django on my local dev
- this is happening from within a virtualenv running python2.5
- I have installed the mimeparse package using pip install -E for that virtualenv
- I have verified this by checking the site packages in my 'something-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages' for the mimeparse.py
- running the python shell lets me import mimeparse
- running python manage.py shell also lets me import mimeparse
- running python manage.py runserver will fail on import mimeparse, but in the pretty django error page I can see that the python path contains the something-env/lib/python2.5/site-packages folder

what can I be doing wrong?

NOTE: copying the mimeparse.py into the project root will work, but that is not exactly pretty.

Comment: are you sure that you are starting runserver with your virtualenv activated?

Answer (score 0):

If you get stuck running Ubuntu, with the following import error: no module named mimeparse, just install it, by adding the following line on your terminal in the appropriate directory :

```
pip install mimeparse
```

There is a debian package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mimeparse
```

But, I didn't need to install the debian package. Just the first command and works for me.

Don't forget to activate your env.

```
source $PYTHON_HOME/activate
```

My $PYTHON_HOME points to my virtualenv python.